# Applescript path to me returning error

Tags: macos, applescript, ui-automation

I have an applescript script (.scpt) with the following function:

```
on scrap_range(min, max)
    repeat with loop from min to max
        tell application "Safari"
            -- Do stuff
        end tell
        tell application "Finder"
            set outputFile to ((container of (path to me)))
        end tell
        display dialog (outputFile as text)
    end repeat
end scrap_range
```

When I run it in Applescript Editor it fails with the following event log output.

```
tell current application
    path to current application
Result:
error "File some object wasn’t found." number -43
```

And it highlights the "path to me" text in the code. Where am I going wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: Same code doesn't show any problems for me. Where is the .scpt file located?

Comment: I'm also getting no errors.  Are you sure you're running it with supply both parameters, cause object wasn't found can be the handler tries to use min or max but it wasn't supplied a value:   scrap_range(1,3)

Comment: When you try set outputFile to ((container of file (path to me))) does it work then? I'm not pasting it as an answer because I'm not sure but the returned object of path to me is now not some object but an file object now. Otherwise you could try to get the path to command outside the finder tell block. It doesn't throws an error but according the the release notes for 10.6 you violate the scripting addition's security.

Comment: I am calling the script in AppleScript Editor and it is saved in a directory in my home directory.

Comment: I am calling it once as scrap_range(800,800)